# C++ Text file Reading and Parsing for text-based adventure game

Tags: c++, windows, file, parsing, file-io

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to programming, but as a small project I decided I'd try to make a VERY simple text-based adventure game just for some fun and practice. I have no idea how these types of games are normally made, but I decided to make a text file containing all the actual text rather than typing it all in the code, so here's what my "gamelocationdata.txt" file currently looks like.

```
[castleStart]
{
=castleStart=
You find yourself in a dark room inside a castle.
The walls are made of mossy stone and the entire room has a very eerie atmosphere.

There is a green bottle on the floor.
There are 2 exits, east and south.
Both exits are large doorways with grand arches.
You can see a large room through the south exit, but the east exit looks very dark and
somewhat frightening.

What will you do?
#"look arch" castleStartLookArch
#"look wall" castleStartLookWall
#"look bottle" castleStartLookBottle itemcond: hasBottle "0"
#"take bottle" castleStartLookBottle itemcond: hasBottle "0"
#"pick bottle" castleStartLookBottle itemcond: hasBottle "0"
#"go south" castleHall
#"go east" castleDark loccond: hasBeenCastleDark "0"
#"wait" castleStartWait
}

[castleStartLookArch]
{
=castleStart=
The arches above the doors look very fancy.
You can't quite figure out why this tiny room deserves to be decorated as such.
#(castleStart)
}

[castleStartLookWall]
{
=castleStart=
The wall is made of stone masonry in an old-fashioned way. 
Some stones are covered in moss and there are cobwebs in the corners.
#(castleStart)
}

[castleStartWait]
{
=castleStart=
You sit still and admire the wall for a while.
Nothing happens.
#(castleStart)
}

[castleStartLookBottle]
{
=castleStart=
You pick the bottle up. It is covered in cobwebs.
The bottle is green and the label reads "1337". It contains a purple liquid.

Do you want to put the bottle in your backpack?
#"yes" castleStartTakeBottle
#"no" castleStartNoTakeBottle
}

[castleStartTakeBottle]
{
=castleStart=
You take the bottle and put it in your backpack.
+item: Bottle1337
+itemcond: hasBottle "1"
#(castleStart)
}

[castleStartNoTakeBottle]
{
=castleStart=
You put the bottle back down again.
#(castleStart)
}

[useBottle1337]
{
=curLocation=
You open the bottle and drink its contents.
It tastes very sweet.

You suddenly feel slightly stronger and more powerful.
+strength: 5
+remove_item: Bottle1337
#(castleStart)
}

[castleHall]
{
=castleHall=
You walk though the southern doorway and enter the grand hall of the castle.
It seems like the entire castle is just as old and worn out as the walls in that room,
though still very nicely decorated.
There are only a few candles on the walls, and they are somehow lit despite
the castle seeming very empty. There is not not a person to be seen.

You can go back north or proceed south through the hall.
#(castleStart)
}

[castleDark]
{
=castleStart=
You slowly tread into the dark room to the east, looking
around you as your surroundings get darker and darker.
Suddenly, you hear a noise. It sounds like the growling of an angry dog!
Horrified, you hastily turn around and run back.
+loccond: hasBeenCastleDark "1"
#(castleStart)
}
```

I realize I may have bitten of more than I can chew, but this is how the formatting I made up is supposed to work:

> Example: **[castleStart]** is the name of a "location", and the curly
>   braces that come after encapsulate everything that has to do with that
>   location.
>
> Example: **=castleStart=** is the location to print for the player when
>   they ask where they currently are.
>
> **The stuff that comes after that** is what will be printed on screen when the player
>   "enters" that location.
>
> **After the location text**, there are a bunch of options that all start
>   with a "#".
>
> Example: **#"wait" castleStartWait** If the player types "wait", they will
>   be taken to the "location" named [castleStartWait].
>
> Example: **#"look bottle" castleStartLookBottle itemcond: hasBottle "0"**
>   If the player types "look bottle", they will be taken to the location
>   named [castleStartLookBottle] as long as they meet the "item
>   requirement" that they do not already have the bottle.
>
> Example: **#"go east" castleDark loccond: hasBeenCastleDark "0"** If the
>   player types "go east", they will be taken to the location named
>   [castleDark] as long as they meet the "location requirement" that they
>   haven't already been there.
>
> Example: **#(castleStart)** This will use the same options as the ones listed in [castleStart].
>
> Example: **+strength: 5** This should add 5 points to the player's "strength" stat when they enter the location and print some hardcoded message like "You have acquired 5 strength points!"

Now, **here's the problem**: How do I write the function that reads and parses the data of a specific location and stores them in specific std::strings?

For example, if I do

```
readAndParseLocationData( castleStart );
```

it should look for [castleStart] in the text file, then read what's between the equals signs (=castleStart=) and store that in "std::string printLoc", then read the text after and store in a "std::string locText" and so on.

This is all the code I have so far:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ClearScreen.h"
#include "LocationData.h"

int main()
{
    ClearScreen();
    std::cout << "I am a banana!\n\n"; // this is just a test

    readAndParseLocationData( "castleHall" );
    printLocationData( "castleStart" ); // this is supposed to be used for debugging the location data by printing it.

    return 0;
}
```

--

```
//LocationData.cpp
#include "LocationData.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void readAndParseLocationData( std::string location )
{
    location.insert( 0,"[" );
    location.append( "]" );
    std::ifstream locfile( "gamelocationdata.txt" );
    if( locfile.is_open() )
    {
        std::string line;
        bool foundFile = false;
        for( unsigned int curLine = 0; getline( locfile,line ); curLine++ )
        {
            if( line.find( location ) != std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout << "found: " << location << ", line: " << curLine << "\n";
                foundFile = true;
            }
        }
        if( !foundFile )
        {
            std::cout << "\nERROR: Location " << location << " not found in data file!\n";
        }
        locfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nERROR: Unable to open location data file!\n";
    }
}
void printLocationData( std::string location )
{
    //TODO: Implement
}
```

All I've managed to make it do (through extensive googling) is look for the location name and print what line it's on to the console.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 on Windows 7.

I'd also love to hear if there is any way to improve my code or formatting in general!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers who happen to stumble upon this 2 year old question, here's the final code I ended up using to parse the location data.

(It's old and not pretty by any means, but note that the solution to my main problem was learning about std::getline and the various manipulation methods of std::string - mainly find() and substr().)

```
struct Location final
{
    std::string displayName;
    std::string optionsName;
    std::string locationText;
    std::string defaultOption;
    std::string shop;
    std::vector<int> battleLevel;
    std::vector<int> battleChanceLevel;
    std::vector<int> battleChancePercentage;
    std::vector<std::string> battleEnemy;
    std::vector<std::string> battleChanceEnemy;
    std::vector<std::string> addItems;
    std::vector<std::string> addWeapons;
    std::vector<std::string> addConds;
    std::vector<std::string> addStats;
    std::vector<std::string> removeItems;
    std::vector<std::string> removeWeapons;
    std::vector<std::string> removeConds;
    std::vector<std::string> removeStats;
    std::unordered_set<std::string> options;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> resultLoc;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> conds;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Location> locationCache;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> locationNewFileCache;

Location& loadLocationData( const std::string& location, const std::string& filename, const bool overRideData, const bool dataFile )
{
    if( ::locationCache.count( location ) && overRideData == false ) // If we already parsed this location...
        return ::locationCache[ location ]; // Return cached data.
    else
    {
        auto filePath = std::string( "game/data/" );
        if( !dataFile )
            filePath.append( "locations/" );
        std::ifstream locFile( filePath + filename );
        if( locFile.is_open() )
        {
            bool foundLoc = false;
            for( std::string line; std::getline(locFile, line); )
            {
                Location parsedLocation;
                if( line.find( "[" + location + "]" ) != std::string::npos )
                {
                    foundLoc = true;

                    // Parse optionsname/next filename.
                    std::string optsName; std::getline( locFile, optsName );
                    if( optsName.find( ".txt" ) != std::string::npos )
                        ::locationNewFileCache[ location ] = optsName;
                    else
                        parsedLocation.optionsName = optsName;

                    // Parse display name.
                    std::string dispName; std::getline( locFile, dispName );
                    parsedLocation.displayName = dispName;

                    // Parse location text.
                    std::string locText;
                    for( std::string scanLine; ( (scanLine.empty()) ? true : scanLine.back() != '}' ) && std::getline( locFile, scanLine ); )
                    {
                        if( !scanLine.empty() && scanLine.front() == '{' )
                            locText = scanLine;
                        else
                            locText.append( "\n" + scanLine );
                    }
                    if( locText.size() >= 2 )
                    {
                        locText.erase( locText.begin() ); // Remove { at beginning.
                        locText.pop_back(); // Remove } at end.
                    }
                    parsedLocation.locationText = locText;

                    // Parse rest.
                    bool endReached = false;
                    for( std::string scanLine; !endReached && std::getline( locFile, scanLine ); )
                    {
                        if( !scanLine.empty() )
                        {
                            switch( scanLine.front() )
                            {
                            case '*': endReached = true; break; // END
                            case '#': // OPTION / DEFAULT OPTION
                                if( scanLine.at( 1 ) == '"' ) // OPTION
                                {
                                    scanLine.erase( 0, 2 );
                                    auto optionName = scanLine.substr( 0, scanLine.find( '\"' ) );
                                    parsedLocation.options.insert( optionName );
                                    scanLine.erase( 0, scanLine.find( '\"' ) + 2 );

                                    auto optionResultLoc = scanLine.substr( 0, scanLine.find( ';' ) );
                                    parsedLocation.resultLoc[ optionName ] = optionResultLoc;
                                    scanLine.erase( 0, scanLine.find( ';' ) + 1 );

                                    if( !scanLine.empty() ) // if the option has conditions...
                                    {
                                        auto condType = scanLine.substr( 0, scanLine.find( ':' ) );
                                        scanLine.erase( 0, scanLine.find( ':' ) + 2 );
                                        if( condType == "loccond" || condType == "itemcond" || condType == "statcond" )
                                            parsedLocation.conds[ optionName ] = scanLine;
                                        else
                                            logError( "Invalid location data syntax in " + filename + "!", "Invalid condition" );
                                    }
                                }
                                else if( scanLine.at( 1 ) == '(' ) // DEFAULT OPTION
                                {
                                    scanLine.erase( 0, 2 );
                                    parsedLocation.defaultOption = scanLine.substr( 0, scanLine.find( ')' ) );
                                }
                                else
                                    logError( "Invalid location data syntax in " + filename + "!", "Neither option nor default option specified" );
                                break;
                            case '+': // ACTION (ITEM / STAT / CONDITION)
                                scanLine.erase( scanLine.begin() );
                                auto action = scanLine.substr( 0, scanLine.find( ':' ) );
                                scanLine.erase( 0, scanLine.find( ':' ) + 2 );
                                auto value = scanLine;

                                if( action == "item" )
                                    parsedLocation.addItems.push_back( value );
                                else if( action == "remove_item" )
                                    parsedLocation.removeItems.push_back( value );
                                else if( action == "weapon" )
                                    parsedLocation.addWeapons.push_back( value );
                                else if( action == "remove_weapon" )
                                    parsedLocation.removeWeapons.push_back( value );
                                else if( action == "itemcond" || action == "loccond" )
                                    parsedLocation.addConds.push_back( value );
                                else if( action == "battle" )
                                {
                                    auto enemyName = value.substr( 0, value.find( ' ' ) );
                                    value.erase( 0, value.find( ' ' ) + 1 );
                                    auto nEnemies = std::stoi( value.substr( 0, value.find( ',' ) ) );
                                    value.erase( 0, value.find( ',' ) + 1 );
                                    auto level = std::stoi( value );
                                    for( auto i = 0; i < nEnemies; ++i )
                                    {
                                        parsedLocation.battleEnemy.push_back( enemyName );
                                        parsedLocation.battleLevel.push_back( level );
                                    }
                                }
                                else if( action == "battlechance" )
                                {
                                    auto enemyName = value.substr( 0, value.find( ' ' ) );
                                    value.erase( 0, value.find( ' ' ) + 1 );
                                    auto chance = std::stoi( value.substr( 0, value.find( ',' ) ) );
                                    value.erase( 0, value.find( ',' ) + 1 );
                                    auto level = std::stoi( value );

                                    parsedLocation.battleChanceEnemy.push_back( enemyName );
                                    parsedLocation.battleChancePercentage.push_back( chance );
                                    parsedLocation.battleChanceLevel.push_back( level );
                                }
                                else if( action == "shop" )
                                    parsedLocation.shop = value;
                                else
                                    parsedLocation.addStats.push_back( action + " " + value ); // Assume it's a stat.
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ::locationCache[ location ] = parsedLocation;
                    return ::locationCache[ location ];
                }
            }
        }
        else
            logError( "Unable to open location data file " + filename + "!" );
    }
    static Location dummyLocation;
    return dummyLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to do is parse the file just-in-time as you come across the locations you wish to access. This is a good idea if you expect your game to become too large to feasibly parse once and store in memory, but for a small example like this, it's probably unnecessary.

However, if you wish to implement this for learning purposes, there are a few things to look into. First of all, your current idea would involve re-parsing the file every time you want to look at the some location. A better idea would be to devise some kind of representation for the location data and implement a cache of some kind. A possible way to do this (only taking the names and location text into account) would be:

```
class Location
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string displayName;
    std::string locationText;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, Location> cache;

Location& readAndParseLocationData( std::string location )
{
    //if we have already parsed this location
    if (cache.count(location))
    {
        return cache[location];
    }
    else
    {
        Location parsed_location{};
        //do the parsing
        cache[location] = parsed_location;
    }
}
```

In order to actually do the parsing, I would write a simple [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). For your case, it would look something like this (in pseudocode):

```
Until we have found the location:
    Look for a location
    If this location matches:
        Read the location into a string
        Look for a opening brace
        Read the location display name into a string
        Read the rest into a string up until a closing brace
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I'm not very good with classes (again, I'm a bit of a noob), but if I understand correctly, this would simply store the location data after parsing it for future reference?

Comment: Yes, it means that you don't need to parse look in the file again next time you want that data, as opening and reading files is expensive.

Comment: Since different locations contain different amounts of options and other information to be stored, how would I create a dynamic class that contains the right amount strings required for that specific location? I shouldn't have to declare every possible string to be stored inside the class, right? Then I could only have a preset number of options.

Comment: Use a data structure such as `std::vector<std::string>` to store varying numbers of strings.

Comment: Okay, I'm still having some problems with the actual parsing of the data. I've been googling for recursive descent parser examples in C++, but I haven't managed to find any good ones (since they're all very specific). I've got a vague idea of how they work, but if you could provide a non-pseudocode example of how to do it in my case, that would be great!